# Sharepoint 2016 Search Topology

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, 2016, topology

Have just installed an 8 Server Sp2016 Farm with MinRoles (2 each) but after creating the Search Service App the Topology Overview in Central Admin only shows one of them.

[image]

Do I have to add the second one manually via PowerShell like in SP13? Will the second one (es4) get any work? Dont really get why it wouldnt auto-deploy on both Servers which got "Search" as MinRole.

Cheers & Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have to provision the search service topology to those servers. Each of the 6 search service application components has to be allocated by you through PowerShell as the admin.

Comment: thank you!
I used this PowerShell-based GUI for configuration, pretty simple to use:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/scottstewart/2015/04/29/powershell-ui-to-modify-sharepoint-search-topology/

Comment: Great, there is also a really good multi-server script associated with this course: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/sharepoint2013-search-back-front